# Copy selected files from one to another location

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to copy 10 files from one folder to another. In the source folder I have 100 files but I need files from 30-40 only.
I have the list of all files.

```
for i in listi:
    shutil.copy(src,dest)
```

This copy the entire files, but I need only 10 from no 30 to 40

Answer (score 0):

Is `listi` your list of files? How are src and dest defined? As is your code would be copying the same `src` to `dest` `len(listi)` times?

Try `for i in listi[30:40]` to get files 30-39 inclusive, but you'd need to then do `shutil.copy(i, dest)` to copy those files.

Comment: Yes. This is helpful for me.